# reference binding to null pointer of type 'struct value_type'

Tags: c++, string

This is leetcode 14.
As leetcode only give one small part of code without the full picture. I can't figure out the problem with my code. The error message doesn't pinpoint to one single line.
Please help me have a look what is going wrong.

This is to find the longest common prefix string among a bunch of strings stored in a vector.
My idea is first find shortest string length among all strings. Then i iterate with this and check whether all strings have the same prefix. If not, return the substr in previous loop.

```
class Solution {
public:
    string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) {
        int min = strs[0].size();
        string prefix;
        for(int i =0;i<strs.size();i++){
            if(strs[i] == "") return "";
            else{
                if(min > (strs[i].size()))
                    min = strs[i].size();
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=min;i++){
            prefix=strs[0].substr(0,i);
            for(int j=0;j<strs.size();j++){
                if(prefix.compare(strs[j].substr(0,i))){
                    return prefix.substr(0,prefix.size()-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: So you have an error, what line or should we guess ?  try an make a [mcve] please.  Re your comment below): not marked you down (yet)  - how can we help you if you can't tell the location of the error.

Comment: have u read my post before you mark down? I mentioned it didn't pinpoint to one line, otherwise i would not even come here to ask.

Comment: BTW, your `string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs)` *member-function* **fails** to return a value.

Comment: @WhiZTiM, thanks, that is the problem. I add another "return prefix" outside the last for loop. How do you correlate the error message to "member function fails to return a value"

Comment: Write yourself a `main` that contains a test rig that exercises `Solution` and you won't have to count on the limited information provided by the online judge. This will also help you pick off the half-dozen compiler warnings that might mean something is going wrong and the one that certainly does.

Comment: @user4581301 ok,

Comment: "How do you correlate the error message to "member function fails to return a value" " this looks like a good case for returning an empty `string`.

Comment: "reference binding to null pointer of type 'struct value_type'" probably comes from `int min = strs[0].size();` when `longestCommonPrefix` is called with an empty `vector`. There is no `strs[0]` to access. One of the first things I would do in my text code is something like `Solution s;
    vector<string> v{};
    cout << s.longestCommonPrefix(v);`. I'd be surprised if leetcode doesn't include a similar test.

Comment: @user4581301, right that is not safe. I add another line at the beginning to make sure if the vector doesn't contain anything, i directly return empty string to eliminate this possible hole

Answer (score 0):

The very first line of your code has a potantial error in it.  Also why don't you use the standard algorithms?  Doing this with algorithms would definitely help you avoid common mistakes...

```
class Solution {
public:
    string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) 
    {
        int min = strs[0].size();  // <-- this line fails if strs is empty.
        //...
    }
};
```

To get the shortest string in a vector of strings, using stl algorithms, could look a bit like this, and be done much quicker than

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

inline bool shorter(const string& s1, const string& s2)
{
    return s1.length() < s2.length();
}

struct has_not_prefix
{
    has_not_prefix(const string& s) : prefix_(s) {}

    bool operator()(const string& s)
    {
        if (s.length() > prefix_.length())
            return false;
        return strncmp(s.c_str(), prefix_.c_str(), prefix_.length()) != 0;
    }

private:
    const string& prefix_;
};

string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) 
{
    vector<string>::iterator 
        shortest = min_element(strs.begin(), strs.end(), shorter);

    if (shortest == strs.end() || shortest->empty())
        return "";

    string prefix;
    prefix.reserve(shortest->length());
    prefix += (*shortest)[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < strs.front().length(); ++i)
    {
        prefix += (*shortest)[i];
        if (find_if(strs.begin() + 1, strs.end(), has_not_prefix(prefix)) != strs.end())
        {
            prefix.resize(prefix.length() - 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return prefix;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    //...

    string r = longestCommonPrefix(v);

    //...
    return 0;
}
```

[PS] don't abuse string::substr(), as it allocates memory everytime you call it.